# How can I get the ID, class or HTML tag of an element that calls my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to use `jQuery.fn.extend()` and it's been working but I want to get the ID, class or html tag that called it. I can't know whether the string calling my `fn` is a tag, ID or class.

For example,

> $('table').scrollify();

I want to be able to get the string `'table'` not `this` inside my `scrollify` function

***Here's my code:***

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollify = function() {
    $('tbody').css({
      'width': Math.ceil($('thead').width() + 17)
    });
    $('tbody > tr > td').css({
      'width': Math.ceil($('thead').width())
    });
    $('thead > tr > th').css({
      'width': $('tbody').width() / $('thead > tr > th').length
    });
    $('tbody').css({
      'margin-top': $('thead').height() - 1
    });
    return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.height();
  };
})(jQuery);

$('table').scrollify();
```

Answer (score 1):

After some tweaking and "consoling" `this` a lot, I found out that I just need to do the following:

`this.selector`

Period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.id` to get id

`this.prop("tagName");` to get tag name

Comment: That's the whole point, I don't know what is going to go through it, whether it's ID, tag, or class